# Having problems with Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$1^n =1$ where n is a positive integer I understand.
But $1^{1/2}$ or $1^{0.5}$ is also $1$, I have difficulty in understanding that.
And does that mean $1^n$ where n is any positive real no equals $1$?
$2^{-5}$ = $1 / 2^5$ = $1/32 =0.03125 $
I can compute this but I really don't understand this law.How can you raise something to negative power and if you can how is it obtained by removing the $-$ sign and dividing it by $1$ ?

Comment: You seem to be stuck using the definition of exponentiation that $a^n$ is defined for $n$ a positive integer exponent as being $\underbrace{a\times a\times \cdots \times a}_{n~\text{times}}$.  This is a very restrictive definition and not the one that is actually used.  The operation of exponentiation has been extended to allow for other exponents other than just positive integers and allows for negative integers, fractions, and any arbitrary real or complex number.

Comment: Although it is not necessary for an elementary student to learn the exact definition (it is useful to know) you should be made aware of basic properties that come as a result of the definition, including but not limited to $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$ and $a^n\times a^m = a^{n+m}$ and others.  These properties can be proven from the rigorous extended definition.

Answer (score 1):

As JMoravitz said, defining $a^n$ as "a multiplied by itself n times" only makes sense for n a positive integer.  We are free to define $a^x$, for x not a positive integer as we please- and we would like to do that so that it has "nice" properties.

One of the "nice" properties that $a^n$ is that $a^{n+ m}= a^{n}a^m$.  To see that imagine writing n+ m copies of n in a row.  That can be separated as the first n copies times the last m copies: $(a^n)(a^m)$.

How should we define $a^0$? Obviously we can't multiply a by itself "0 times"!  But 0 is the additive identity.  For any n, n+ 0= n.  If we want $a^{n+m}= (a^n)(a^m)$ true even when m= 0 we must have $a^n= a^{n+ 0}= (a^n)(a^0)$.  In order to have $a^n= (a^n)(a^0)$ we must **define** $a^0= 1$.

"Negative integers" are the additive inverses of the positive integers.  Any negative integer can be written "-n" for some positive integer n such that n+ (-n)= 0.  Then we want $a^{n+(-n)}= (a^n)(a^{-n})= a^0= 1$.  So we must **define** $a^{-n}= \frac{1}{a^n}$. For that to make sense we must require that a is not 0.

The set of rational numbers is defined "multiplicatively": if r is any non-zero number then there exist $\frac{1}{r}$ such that $r\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)= 1= r^0$.  For that we need a multiplicative property.  For positive integers, m and n, and any number a, $(a^m)^n= a^{mn}$.  to see that, think of $(a^m)^n$ as n rows, each row consisting of m copies of a.  There is a total of mn a's in that "rectangle" of a's.

Now, we want to **define** $a^{1/n}$ so that property still holds.  That is, we want $\left(a^{1/n}\right)^n= a^{(1/n)n}= a^1= a$. In order that this be true we have to define $a^{1/n}= \sqrt[n]{n}$, the "principle" nth root which, as long as a is a positive real number, is a positive real number.  And, in order that this be "well defined", we must require that a be a positive real number.

Finally, we have to define $a^x$ for x any real number. The set of real numbers cannot be defined "algebraically"- they have to be defined "analytically", with some kind of limit process.  The simplest way to do that is to define a real number as an equivalence class of **sequences** of rational numbers.  For example, we can think of the real number $\pi$ as defined by the sequence of rational numbers {3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, 3.14159, …}.  For any positive a, we would define $a^{\pi}$ as the limit of the sequence $\{a^3, a^{3.1}, a^{3.14}, a^{3.141}, a^{3.1415}, a^{3.14159}, …\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of definition and fitting things into the definition.

Consider this process of learning.

Definition 1:  If $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $n \ge 2$ then $b^n = \underbrace{b\cdot b\cdot..\cdot b}_{n\text{ times}}$.

From there it's easy to verify that $b^nb^m = b^{n+m}$ and that $(b^n)^m = b^{n*m}$ and if $n \ge m+2$ the $\frac{b^n}{b^m} = b^{n-m}$.  This becomes our fundamental law:

Fundamental law:  $b^nb^m = b^{n+m}$ and $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$.

We want to *extend* our definition of $b^x$ from Definition 1: where we have it it defined for $x\in \mathbb Z$ and $n \ge 2$ to $x\in \mathbb R$, but where a) if $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \ge 2$ our new definition will give the same value as Def 1 and b)  Our fundamental law must be true.

For us to do this we must have:  $b^0*b^k = b^{k+0} = b^k$.  That means $b^0$ *must* equal $1$ and we must have $b^{-k}b^{k} = b^{-k+k} = b^0 = 1$.  This means that $b^{-k} = \frac 1{b^k}$.  (This also means that we can define $0^n$ for $n\in Z$.

So we have

Definition 2:  If $b\ne 0$ then $b^0 = 1$.  $b^1 = b$ and if $k \in \mathbb Z; k \ge 2$, $b^k$ is defined as in Definition 1; but if $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $k < 0$ then $k = -|k|$ and $b^{k} = b^{-|k|} = \frac 1{b^{|k|}}$.

Now our fundamental law says that $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$ so $(b^{\frac 1k})^k = b^{\frac 1k * k} = b^1=b$ so we *must* have that $b^{\frac 1k}$ be one of the $k$th roots of $b$.

Now only positive numbers are guaranteed to have roots so this leads to definition three:

Definition 3:  If $b > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb Q$ and $k = \frac mn$ where $m,n\in \mathbb Z$ then $b^k =  b^{\frac mn} = \sqrt[n]{b^m}$ where $m \in \mathbb Z$ and $b^m$ is defined as in Definition 2.

Now, I'm going to wave my hands in discussing $b^x$ where $x \in \mathbb R$.  Every real number $x$ will have a sequence of rational numbers $q_i$ where $q_i \to x$.  If it's easier to think about it, you can consider the $q_i$ as the decimal expansions $x$.  If $q_i\to x$ then (you'll have to trust me on this) $b^{q_i} \to M$ for some real number $M$.

Definition 4:  If $b > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} q_n = x$ for some sequence of rational $q_n$ then $b^x$ will be defined as $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}b^{q_n}$ where $b^{q_n}$ is defined as in definition 3.

======

So... to your questions.

If $1^{\frac 12} = w$ then $(1^{\frac 12})^2 = 1^1 = 1 =w^2$ so $w =\sqrt 1 = 1$.

"And does that mean $1^n$ where n is any positive real no equals 1?"

Yes.  It does.  And $n$ doesnt just have to be positive real. $n$ could be zero or negative.

And what about $2^{-5}$?

If $2^{-5} = w$ then then $2^5*2^{-5} = 2^5 * w$ and so $2^5*2^{-5}=2^{5-5}=2^0 = 1 = 2^5*w = 32w$.  So $w = 2^{-5} = \frac 1{32}$.

Answer (score 0):

The general definition is given by $$a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}$$ so $$2^{-5}=e^{-5\ln(2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{x}, x^{-n} = (x^{-1})^n, x^{m/n} = \sqrt[n]{x^m}$$ are all definitions. The reason for the notation is to work nicely with the laws of exponents you already know. The intuition for $2^{-5}$ no longer means "multiply -5 copies of 2 together".

Answer (score 0):

As David Peterson stated, $x^{-n}=\frac{1}{x^n}$ is a definition.

I want to give an easy motivation why one would chose $x^{-n}$ to be defined as $\frac{1}{x^n}$.

First notice, that you want all the rules you know for exponents also to work with negative exponents. So $x^{-n}$ should be equal to $(x^n)^{-1}$.

Take now the product $x^n\cdot x^{-n}$. If we want all the laws of exponents to work with the definition of $x^{-n}$, this product could be rewritten in the following way: $x^n\cdot x^{-n}=(x^n)^1\cdot (x^n)^{-1}=(x^n)^{1+(-1)}=(x^n)^0=1$. So we have $x^n\cdot x^{-n}=1$, which is why you choose $x^{-n}$ to be $\frac{1}{x^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$1^N = 1$ for any real value of N.

You are OK with the case of N being integer. This is good start.

The case where $N$ is not integer, as in your example: $1^{0.5}$ (also referred to as $\sqrt{1}$) could be justified as follows:

What is the number $x$ that if you multiply it by itself, you get 1?

This calls for solving the equation $$x^2=1$$ Taking the square root of both sides, we get two numbers that satisfy the equation, namely the number $+1$ and the number $-1$.

That is for the **$+1$** case: $$\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{1}=1^{0.5}=1$$

I hope that his is somewhat convincing.

As for the negative powers part, think of how you would do $\frac{4^3}{4^5}$, you may want to write it down as where the "." is a multiplication sign:

$$K=\frac{4^3}{4^5} = \frac{4.4.4}{4.4.4.4.4}=\frac{1}{4.4}$$

If you notice the powers of the numerator (3) and the denominator (5) and compare them with the power of the denominator (2), you may observe that $5-3=2$. That is we could write:

$$K=\frac{4^3}{4^5}=\frac{1}{4^{5-3}}=\frac{1}{4^{2}}$$

Suppose now we want to calculate $Z$ by multiplying $K$ by $4^7$:

$$Z=4^{7}\frac{1}{4^{2}}$$

Using the above approach:

$$Z=4^{7}\frac{1}{4^{2}}=\frac{4.4.4.4.4.4.4}{4.4}=4.4.4.4.4=4^5$$

Observe the powers here:

$$Z=4^{7}\frac{1}{4^{2}}=4^5$$

Do you see that $7-2=7+(-2)=5$?

The (-2) here is what you use the negative power for.

That is why we can do:
$$Z=4^{7}.4^{-2}=4^{7-2}=4^5$$

and we can do $$K=\frac{4^3}{4^5}=4^{3-5}=4^{-2}=\frac{1}{4^2}$$

This may be a good read: [What do Fractional Exponents mean](https://medium.com/i-math/what-do-fractional-exponents-mean-1bb9bd2fa9a8)